# Modeshape workspace creation

Tags: jboss, jcr, modeshape

We are working with this platform:

JBoss 6.1.0.GA

Modeshape 3.6.0

I just need to create a new workspace and to put inside images,javascripts, and other files I need for a webapp we are developing.

I tried to connect via webdav to our modeshape repository and create a new test directory inside, but I always receive this exception:

```
2015-02-03 16:47 WARN  [org.modeshape.web.jcr.webdav.ModeShapeWebdavStore] (http-/0.0.0.0:8021-1) Cannot obtain a session for the repository 'repository': The workspace test was not found
```

I looked on stackoverflow and on the official guide of modeshape, but I still cannot catch how to do this "easy" task.

It seems there's no documentation that explains how to manually create a new workspace in a repository.

I add the configurations from standalone.xml I'm using for cache:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.4">
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="modeshape" default-cache="repository" module="org.modeshape">
            <local-cache name="repository">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <string-keyed-jdbc-store datasource="java:/jdbc/blablablaDatasource" shared="true" passivation="false" purge="false">
                    <property name="databaseType">
                        oracle
                    </property>
                    <property name="createTableOnStart">
                        true
                    </property>
                    <string-keyed-table prefix="CONTENT_REPO_STRING">
                        <id-column name="id_column" type="VARCHAR2(255)"/>
                        <data-column name="data_column" type="BLOB"/>
                        <timestamp-column name="timestamp_column" type="NUMBER(20)"/>
                    </string-keyed-table>
                </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="binary_cache_container" default-cache="binary_fs">
            <local-cache name="binary_fs">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <string-keyed-jdbc-store datasource="java:/jdbc/blablablaDatasource" shared="true" preload="false" passivation="false" purge="false">
                    <write-behind flush-lock-timeout="1" modification-queue-size="1024" shutdown-timeout="25000" thread-pool-size="1"/>
                    <property name="databaseType">
                        oracle
                    </property>
                    <string-keyed-table prefix="CONTENT_REPO">
                        <id-column name="id_column" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <data-column name="data_column" type="BLOB"/>
                        <timestamp-column name="timestamp_column" type="NUMBER(20)"/>
                    </string-keyed-table>
                </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="binary_fs_meta">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <string-keyed-jdbc-store datasource="java:/jdbc/blablablaDatasource" shared="true" preload="false" passivation="false" purge="false">
                    <write-behind flush-lock-timeout="1" modification-queue-size="1024" shutdown-timeout="25000" thread-pool-size="1"/>
                    <property name="databaseType">
                        oracle
                    </property>
                    <string-keyed-table prefix="CONTENT_REPO">
                        <id-column name="id_column" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
                        <data-column name="data_column" type="BLOB"/>
                        <timestamp-column name="timestamp_column" type="NUMBER(20)"/>
                    </string-keyed-table>
                </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
```

and also for the modeshape conf:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modeshape:1.0">
        <repository name="repository" security-domain="modeshape-internal-security">
            <workspaces default-workspace="default" allow-workspace-creation="true">
                <workspace name="ops">
                    <initial-content>
                        initial-content-default.xml
                    </initial-content>
                </workspace>
        <workspace name="other"/>
        <workspace name="extra">
            <initial-content>
                        initial-content-default.xml
                    </initial-content>
                </workspace>    
        <workspace name="default"/>
            </workspaces>
            <indexing rebuild-upon-startup="ALWAYS"/>
            <cache-binary-storage data-cache-name="binary_fs" metadata-cache-name="binary_fs_meta" cache-container="binary_cache_container"/>
            <sequencers>
                <sequencer name="fixed-width-text-sequencer" classname="org.modeshape.sequencer.text.FixedWidthTextSequencer" module="org.modeshape.sequencer.text" commentMarker="#" path-expression="/files(//*.txt[*])/jcr:content[@jcr:data] => /derived/text/fixedWidth/$1"/>
                <sequencer name="xml-sequencer" classname="xml" module="org.modeshape.sequencer.xml" path-expression="/files(//)*.xml[*]/jcr:content[@jcr:data] => /derived/xml/$1"/>
                <sequencer name="image-sequencer" classname="image" module="org.modeshape.sequencer.image" path-expression="/files(//*.(png|jpg|gif)[*])/jcr:content[@jcr:data] => /derived/image/$1"/>
            </sequencers>
            <text-extractors>
                <text-extractor name="tika-extractor" classname="tika" module="org.modeshape.extractor.tika"/>
            </text-extractors>
        </repository>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it work only changing the configuration to this one:

JBoss 6.3.0.GA

Modeshape 3.8.1

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new workspace programmatically using the standard JCR API (see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820396/create-new-workspace), but you can also define workspaces in the ModeShape configuration file.

Since you're deploying ModeShape to JBoss EAP, you can configure new workspaces in the ModeShape subsystem configuration within the installation's [standalone-modeshape.xml](https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/modeshape-3.6.1.Final/deploy/jbossas/kit/jboss-eap61/standalone/configuration/standalone-modeshape.xml#L221) file. Here's an example (that actually is in that configuration file) to define 3 workspaces named `default`, `other`, and `extra` upon startup, defines some [initial content](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE40/Initial+Content) for the workspace named `default`, and it enables the programmatic creation of workspaces.

```
<repository name="artifacts">
  <!-- ... -->
  <!-- Define 3 workspaces to exist upon startup -->
  <workspaces default-workspace="default" allow-workspace-creation="false">
    <workspace name="default">
      <initial-content>initial-content-default.xml</initial-content>
    </workspace>
    <workspace name="other"/>
    <workspace name="extra"/>
  </workspaces>
  <!-- ... -->
<repository name="artifacts">
```

The structure of this XML fragment is dictated by the [modeshape_1_0.xsd](https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/modeshape-3.6.1.Final/deploy/jbossas/modeshape-jbossas-subsystem/src/main/resources/schema/modeshape_1_0.xsd#L57) file in your EAP installation (or the [modeshape_2_0.xsd](https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/master/deploy/jbossas/modeshape-jbossas-subsystem/src/main/resources/schema/modeshape_2_0.xsd) file in Wildfly installations).

For those not deploying ModeShape in JBoss EAP (or Wildfly for ModeShape 4.x), you can do the same thing in ModeShape's JSON configuration file. For example, this defines exactly the same workspaces described above:

```
"workspaces" : {
    "predefined" : ["other", "extra"],
    "default" : "default",
    "allowCreation" : true,
    "initialContent" : {
        "default" : "initial-content-default.xml"
    }
},
```

See ModeShape's [JSON schema](https://github.com/ModeShape/modeshape/blob/modeshape-3.6.1.Final/modeshape-jcr/src/main/resources/org/modeshape/jcr/repository-config-schema.json#L552) for more details and options.

Also, be sure that when you log into a `Session` that you correctly specify the workspace name.

Comment: I updated the question, I already read your answer tips on the guide, but it doesn't let me to create and reach a new workspace.

Comment: I changed environment and now it works. Luckily we are going to upgrade environment in production so I got lucky.